# java put 'UTF-8' String to java.lang.Object crushing

Tags: spring, object, utf-8, character-encoding, hashmap

I have some code like below.

```
HashMap<String, Object> hash = new HashMap<String, Object>();
String str = "한UTF-8 #1글";
hash.put("num", 1);
hash.put("str", str);
```

And my controller here.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/test"}, headers={"Accept=application/json"} produces={"text/plain; charset=UTF-8"})
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<byte[]> test() throws Exception{
HashMap<String, Object> hash = new HashMap<String, Object>();
hash = "*****I put the hashmap which is upper code block here";

Iterator iter = hash.keySet().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
String key = iter.next();
Object val = hash.get(key);
log.info("한UTF-8 String#2글 : [ key : " + " ] [ val : " + val.toString() + " ]");
}
//jackson asl lib for JSON
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
return om.writeValueAsBytes(hash);
}
```

Standard charset of the project is 'UTF-8'. And all messages print fine as UTF-8. I guess putting UTF-8 String to java.lang.Object is the cause of crushing UTF-8.

How Can I fix this?

I already tried :

=in upper block=

- before put String to Object, new String(str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
- change type to byte[], hash.put("str", str.getBytes("UTF-8"));

=in lower block=

- added httpheaders to code like below

  HttpHeaders responseheader = new HttpHeaders();
  responseheader.add("Context-Type", "text/json; charset=UTF-8");
  ...
  return new ResponseEntity(om.writeValueAsBytes(hash), responseheaders, HttpStatus.CREATE);
- in return phrase, om.writeValueAsString(hash).getBytes("UTF-8");

=configurations=

- adding message converter to root-context.xml like below.

> ```
> <mvc:annotation-driven>
>   <mvc:message-converters>
>       <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
>           <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
>               <list>
>                   <value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value>
>               </list>
>           </property>
>       </bean>
>   </mvc:message-converters>
> </mvc:annotation-driven>
> ```

===*** Conditions ===

- Return type should be byte[], because its purpose is sending bson, not json.
- Can not change server.xml.

Thanks for reading and sharing my problem :D

Comment: You never say what is wrong with the code.

Comment: If `val.toString()` in your log statement above looks correct, then the error can't be using Object as type for `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do first is write a unit test for this:

```
HashMap<String, Object> hash = new HashMap<String, Object>();
String str = "한UTF-8 #1글";
hash.put("str", str);

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
byte[] data = om.writeValueAsBytes(hash);
assertEquals("...", new String(data, "UTF-8"));
```

If this test works, then your problem must be somewhere else. If this test fails, there is no need to look at the 1.5 million other places.

Comment: My problem was broken Strings in browser. And as you said my problem had some other cause. I do not know why, but when I reboot my PC this morning it works.

Comment: That's not a good sign. I still suggest to add some test cases so you can be sure that most sources of the bug can't be the cause. That way, you can concentrate on the stuff which you can't test easily.

Comment: Thanks for advising. I will to that whenever I got some free time. Thanks